# multiple query into one?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How do put this into one query?

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM `result` WHERE status = 'new' AND YEAR(`end_date`)  = '2012' limit 20
SELECT * FROM `result` WHERE status = 'new' AND YEAR(`end_date`)  = '2013' limit 20
SELECT * FROM `result` WHERE status = 'new' AND YEAR(`end_date`)  = '2014' limit 20
SELECT * FROM `result` WHERE status = 'new' AND YEAR(`end_date`)  = '2015' limit 20

SELECT * FROM `result` WHERE status = 'new' AND DAY(`end_date`)  = '1' limit 20
SELECT * FROM `result` WHERE status = 'new' AND DAY(`end_date`)  = '2' limit 20
... and to 31

and same for the Month Jan to Dec
```

Basically show 20 records of each day, month and year.

Comment: 32 days in a month :-)? The obvious answer is to use a lot of `union`s.

Comment: I think you could probably come up with views that select the top 20 records (but I can't help but notice you're not ordering...) and select from that.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have functionality like `row_number()`.  This makes it extremely hard to get `20 records per group` instead of `just 20 records`.  This means that writing each query independantly (and possibly using `UNION` to combine the results) really is the most straight forward option.

Comment: are you missing order by clause ? or you are taking any 20 recordds?

Comment: @JoeGJoseph taking any 20 records is fine..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can merge result set using [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) in this way :

```
SELECT * FROM `result` WHERE status = 'new' AND YEAR(`end_date`)  = '2012' limit 20
UNION
SELECT * FROM `result` WHERE status = 'new' AND YEAR(`end_date`)  = '2013' limit 20
UNION
SELECT * FROM `result` WHERE status = 'new' AND YEAR(`end_date`)  = '2014' limit 20
UNION
SELECT * FROM `result` WHERE status = 'new' AND YEAR(`end_date`)  = '2015' limit 20
UNION
SELECT * FROM `result` WHERE status = 'new' AND DAY(`end_date`)  = '1' limit 20
UNION 
SELECT * FROM `result` WHERE status = 'new' AND DAY(`end_date`)  = '2' limit 20
ORDER BY submit_date DESC
```

Comment: Where would you include `order by submit_date desc`?

Comment: 'UNION ALL' does not remove duplicate which I would prefer 'UNION'

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use a stored function instead maybe something like that may help you

```
create function MyRecords()
RETURNS @MyResultsTable table
BEGIN
    select * into @MyResultsTable from ? where ?
    select * into @MyResultsTable from ? where ?
    select * into @MyResultsTable from ? where ?
    select * into @MyResultsTable from ? where ?
    .....
    .....
    .....
end
```

I do not have MySql installed now but you should try to create it from the console and call it. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM `result` WHERE status = 'new' AND YEAR(`end_date`)  >= '2012' AND YEAR(`end_date`) <= '2015' AND DAY(`end_date`)  >= '1' AND DAY(`end_date`)  <= '32' AND  MONTH(`end_date`)  >= '1' AND  MONTH(`end_date`)  <= '12'  limit 20
```

Does this do, what you want?